# Get count of records of a table which return from stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure, which is returning a table. I just want the count of the records is it possible

**My Procedure**

```
create procedure Test
as begin
select * From Student
end
```

exec Test
will give the records out put 
I want the count

NB: I need the sp to return the results of select statement.In another place I need the count of the records returned by sp and columns in the student table is dynamic.

I am expecting an answer without modifying stored procedure.

Comment: @vkp I have edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You can select the data into a temporary table like below.  However, you have to use `OPENQUERY` to do so.  You must also enable data access on your server first.

`Exec sp_serveroption 'ServerName', 'data access', 'true'`

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM OPENQUERY("ServerName", 'EXEC Test')

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TempTable
```

Comment: ,I already tried this and this is possible but columns in student table is dynamic for my scnario(it can be changed per requirement changes)

Comment: I tried this as well this was possible for function but did not work for sp

Comment: Sorry @mike I already tried this not helpful for sp. Could not write select statement for sp

Comment: I am getting error saying "   Server 'my_server_name' is not configured for DATA ACCESS."

Answer (score 0):

> NB: I need the sp to return the results of select statement.

Use your stored procedure as is. That is,

```
create procedure Test
as begin
select * From Student
end
```

> In another place I need the count of the records returned by sp and
>   columns in the student table is dynamic.

If this other place is another SP, then use `rowcount`. You use it this way :

```
EXEC    [sp_WhateverTheSPNameIs]
select @@rowcount
```

Read about [@@RowCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx). This is all you need.

Comment: This won't work as the question states the fields in the table are dynamic.  You are specifying fields to group by which can't be done if you don't know what the field names are.

Comment: Sorry @satwik , I have used one select statement in my question to simplyfy the question. Actually each and every column coming from several master tables and around 20 columns I am expecting as output.even if I group by all columns. My performance also will decrease. I am expecting an answer without modifying sp

Comment: @NithilaShanmugananthan I've edited my answer. Check the edit section within it.

Comment: Sorry @satwik, I already tried it. For me its giving 0 as answer,even I have number of records as output